# Origin of the term "understudy"

Tags: etymology

I've recently seen a musical and, on the night I went, three roles were being played by **understudies** instead of the regular actors.

This term has always puzzled me, partly because I've never found a satisfactory translation for it in my native tongue. However, while I well understand its meaning and although I've researched various dictionaries, I haven't found clear indications of its origin. The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=understudy&searchmode=none) deals with the word in one line and the [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/understudy), normally so generous with references to the origin of terms, doesn't even try.

Can anyone tell me how this word came into existence?

Comment: What do you hope to learn from the origin?

Comment: @MattЭллен. I'm curious to understand what the reasons are behind the choice of terms. If Jay is right and the two actors work together, it would be something similar to what happened with other kinds of artists in the past (e.g. Cimabue and Giotto for painting). However, according to the dictionary, the term seems to have been coined quite recently, more or less one century ago.

Comment: Could somebody please explain how this is general reference or post a link to a standard internet reference source that answers the question?

Comment: @Paola, since it's closed, I can't answer, but I would go (in the absence of anything more substantive) with some lesser senses of *under-* and *study* that NOAD lists: "lower in status; subordinate" and "[with adj. ] a person who learns a skill or acquires knowledge at a specified speed : *I'm a quick study.* [ORIGIN: originally theatrical slang, referring to an actor who memorizes a role.]"

Comment: [Here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=understudy&searchmode=none) is the etymology, from Etymonline. This is our go to site for etymology.

Comment: @zpletan. I appreciate your explanation. However, I feel there should be something else to it, otherwise the same kind of reasoning could be applicable in various fields. Anyone who is in a junior position could be defined an "understudy" as they are learning a profession/trade/... following the instructions (and possibly the example) of someone more experienced. It seems not to be the case. And I find it strange that in dictionaries this term is so sparsely defined. P.S. What would be a standard internet reference source apart from Online Etymology Dictionary?

Comment: @MattЭллен. I regret to say that you quoted exactly the same source which I linked in my post, but I find it difficult to believe that you find that explanation satisfactory.

Comment: The [under prefix](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/under-) can be found at dictionary.com as can the definition of study.

Comment: @MattЭллен. Thank you, I was not familiar with Dictionary.com; however, there seems to be a misunderstanding. I was in no doubt as to the meaning of the term, I just wanted to know how it had come into use, and there is precious little about its origin in any of the dictionaries or links mentioned so far. Still I accept the fact that some of you don't seem to share my opinion and consider my question too basic.

Comment: I see. No, there is no story recorded for this word's origin. Like so many words it just started to be used.

Comment: Sure, the idea of a junior employee being available to fill in for the senior must exist in every field. Why isn't the term used outside of acting? I don't know, I'm sure there are lots of words that COULD be used in fields other than where they actually are used. I suppose there is the difference that in acting, the understudy doesn't per se have another job besides being available to fill in. In most fields we call the person an "assistant" and they can perform other tasks when not filling in for the senior person.

Comment: Of all the words that exist in any language only a bare minority are pure, unadulterated, original roots. The majority are "coined" words, forms that have been in one way or another created, augmented, cut down, combined, and recombined to convey new needed meanings, The language mint is more than a mint; it is a great manufacturing center, where all sorts of productive activities go on unceasingly. Mario Pei, The Story of Language

Comment: Just as an addendum. I'm surprised to notice that my question is considered not correct or suitable months after it was originally posted (and closed). It received another downvote a few minutes ago and I just wonder why.

Comment: @Paola  It's originally theatre slang. Already in Shakespeare's time, actors were said to "study" their lines; by the early 18th Century we spoke of "studying the parts" in which they were cast - we now say we're "preparing the role". When toward the end of the 18th Century long runs with detailed staging superseded daily change of plays, it became necessary to have somebody "understudy" each part in case the principal actor should be indisposed. Eventually the action was applied to the actor, and the verb became the noun. But we still understudy (v.) parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English we regularly say that person A "studied under" person B, meaning that B was the teacher of A. "Study" should be plain enough: that's the common meaning of the word. To say that one person is "under" another means that he is subordinate or junior.

So an "understudy" is one who "studies under" another. In acting, the idea is that the junior actor is supposed to be learning from the senior actor, either by direct instruction or at least by example.

Comment: So, according to what you have posted, the two actors study the same role more or less at the same time, so that the "junior" actor may learn from the more experienced one. I thought that the two people worked independently of one another, and that a less important actor may be called in to replace the more important one without their having ever been together before.

Comment: I'll readily yield to anyone with more knowledge of the acting business, but yes, my understanding is that the understudy studies the same role as the senior actor, and is available to fill in in case of illness, etc. I think this mainly applies to live theater as opposed to TV or movies, where they'd probably just reschedule the shooting. An understudy may have a minor role in addition to being available to substitute -- the kind of role that is listed on the credits as "third man in restaurant".